# Best way to import MongoDB data in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a MongoDB database (the Bitnami one) hosted on Azure. I want to import the data there to use it in my Azure Machine Learning experiment.

Currently, I am exporting the data to **.csv** using **mongoexport** and then copy/pasting it to the **"Enter Manually Data"** module. This is fine for small amounts of data but I would prefer to have a more robust technique for larger databases.

I also thought about using the **"Import Data"** module from http url along with the **http port (28017) of my mongodb** instance but read this was not the recommended use of the http mongodb feature.

Finally, I have installed **cosmosDB** instead of my bitnami MongoDB and it worked fine but this thing **costs an arm** when used with sitecore (it reaches around 100€ per day) and we can't afford it so I switched back to by Mongo.

So is there a better way to export data from Mongo to Azure ML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to use a Python code block in AzureML, something like this:

```
import pandas as p
import pymongo as m

def azureml_main():
    c = m.MongoClient(host='host_IP')
    a = p.DataFrame(c.database_names())
    return a
```